# Mongo Db query to match and add field in document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a `mongodb` query which shows the results if the document has `dataType` as `cheese` and then add a new field in those document `"dataNum": "2"`.
For this, I can use

```
db.veg.aggregate([
    { $match : {"dataType":"cheese" }},
    ])
```

but what query to use so that it can add a new field as well. I am using `nosqlbooster` to query mongodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use updateMany instead of aggregate like this

```
db.veg.updateMany({dataType: "cheese"}, {$set:{dataNum: 2}});
```